# How to properly use GridView to create items on SharePoint Lists?

Tags: web-part, splistitem, asp.net, gridview, viewstate

I'm trying to transfer values from a GridView web-control I'm using in a webpart into a SharePoint list, but whenever I click "save" the data isn't being kicked into the list. All that happens is a new item gets created on the list, one that has no name and none of the fields are filled in. What do I do? Been reading on View State, client side vs server side issues, and none of it is working.

when they click the button:

```
protected void btnSaveAsDraft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ID = 0;
        string confirmValue = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["confirm_value"];
        AddGridRecords(ID);
        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;


        Page.Response.Redirect(web.Url + "/SitePages/Home.aspx?");
    }

private void AddGridRecords(int ID)
    {
        try
        {
            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
            SPList List = web.Lists["FORM D List"];
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            SPListItem NewItem = List.Items.Add();
            NewItem.Update();

            CreateDataTable();

            DataTable tableContext;

            tableContext = CreateDataTable();

            foreach (GridViewRow row in FormDGrid.Rows)
           // for (int count = 0; count < FormDGrid.Rows.Count; count++)
            {                                        
                NewItem["State"] = ((Label)FormDGrid.FindControl("StateField")).Text;
                NewItem["County"] = ((DropDownList)FormDGrid.FindControl("CountyField")).Text;
                NewItem["City or Town"] = ((TextBox)FormDGrid.FindControl("CityField")).Text;
                NewItem.Update();
                List.Update();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Comment: I guess issue might be in code. Share your code here.

Comment: alright. it is there.

Comment: are you updating all grid rows or do you want only selected row of grid to be updated in the list

Comment: I wanted all grid rows to be reflected as new items in the list with the controls holding in the user's inputs filling in the fields on that list. and I think I've narrowed down the problem. the code is actually unable to find the controls holding the values such as County or City.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code

```
private void AddGridRecords(int ID)
    {
        try
        {
            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
            SPList List = web.Lists["FORM D List"];
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            CreateDataTable();

            DataTable tableContext;

            tableContext = CreateDataTable();

            foreach (GridViewRow row in FormDGrid.Rows)
            {
                SPListItem NewItem = List.Items.Add();
                NewItem["State"] = ((Label)FormDGrid.FindControl("StateField")).Text;
                NewItem["County"] = ((DropDownList)FormDGrid.FindControl("CountyField")).Text;
                NewItem["City or Town"] = ((TextBox)FormDGrid.FindControl("CityField")).Text;
                NewItem.Update();                

            }
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
}
```